# Upgrading ungrounded switches to Decora

Tags: electrical

While upgrading to new switches I'm encountering 2-gang boxes with old ungrounded switches, although the boxes have 4-5 ground wires crimped together. They are just not connected to the old switches. What is the best way to ground the new switches?  Space is limited.  In some cases, I cut off the crimp which is at the end of the ground bundle and used a 5 wire Wago to add a wire to ground.

Is this preferable to using a wire nut?  If there are 4 ground wires and 2 switches, I need 6 grounds and the Wago is limited to 5 wires.  I could run another ground wire and then pigtail to two new grounds for the switches. But that is a lot of wires for the box!

Comment: Are the boxes metal or plastic?  Metal boxes can be ground path.

Comment: If boxes are plastic, are you able to determine which cables are for the switches, and which cables may be for outlets?  If you can separate out the switch cables, I believe you can just ground them to their respective switches.

Comment: Photos, please, of the open boxes with wiring.

Comment: Sorry no photo now as this is at my rental property.  However, crip659 brings up a good point. The boxes are metal.  So will the switch be grounded just by screwing to the metal box? If this is true, the original switches were grounded by contact too.  I can run continuity from the ground bundle to the box and/or switch to confirm. This is my 3rd 80-90s era property upgrade and they all seem to have a bundle of ground wires  crimped by a tiny metal "sleeve" that cannot be removed.  Thanks for all the help!!!!